# Nested foreach for deleting and re-inserting only inserting last element

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

So, I have an array of users, and each user has an ID and a list of games. I store it in my database as pairs of userID and gameID.

Every time I'm going to change the games for each user, I need to wipe the old ones and then insert the new ones, so I did this:

```
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $where['id_user'] = $user->id;
            $this->tableUsersGames->delete($where);
            foreach($user->games as $game){
                $data['id_user'] = $user->id;
                $data['id_game'] = $game->id;
                $this->tableUsersGames->insert($data);
            }
        }
```

But it only inserts the last user/games in the list. What I did to solve this was to instead have two `foreach` loops, one for deleting the data, and then another one to insert it, so it's now working fine.

What I wanted to know is why didn't this work? I even put some echoes in there to make sure it was running the right order, and it was.

OK, editing for clarification.

The $users variable looks like this:

```
[
 {id: 1, games: [
   {id: 3, name: 'xyz'},
   {id: 5, name: 'xyz'}
  ]
 },
 {id: 2, games: [
   {id: 2, name: 'xyz'},
   {id: 9, name: 'xyz'}
  ]
 }
]
```

And the framework does exactly what you'd expect it to do, no commit needed.

Comment: I'm not sure anyone can answer this question without a lot more context regarding what $users contains and what the delete and insert methods do.

Comment: What kind of framework do you use? Is it possible that, even if you call `delete` and `insert` here and there, only the last call leads to database action? Maybe, something like `commit` calls are missing?

Comment: May be you should delete first for all users instead of combining it with insert.. by running outer for each only..

Comment: @numbtongue That's what he said he did to fix it, he's wondering why interleaving didn't work.

Comment: @Davit Use backticks to mark code in comments, not bold.

Comment: What is the value of `$where` before the loop? I suspect you just need to empty it first, and probably the same for `$data`.

Comment: Try this `$data = []; foreach($user->games as $game){ $data[]['id_user'] = $user->id; $data[]['id_game'] = $game->id; } $this->tableUsersGames->insert($data);`

Comment: @Barmar Tried that, it's not the problem. The variable doesn't exist outside of the loop, and the value is correcly updated every time before the delete command. Same for the `$data` variable.

Comment: So it's calling `insert()` 4 times, with different `$data` each time, but they're all being ignored except the last one?

Comment: It could be to do with changing a list size while you are looping through it..

Comment: @Barmar Pretty much. And if I put them in different loops it works without any alteration to the code. The only explanation I could think of was that the `delete()` function is deleting everything.

Comment: Even that wouldn't explain it, since you insert 2 games after the last delete, so you should end up with all the games for the last user, not just their last game.

Comment: @Barmar I'm sorry, I end up with both inserts in the last run. Now I'm trying to find out why the last `delete()` is deleting everything.